# WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-poetry, docker-build

I get this Warning message in Docker image Build stage. Is there anyway to supress this warning ?
i want to keep using root though.

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.8.11-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.1.13

RUN python3 -m pip install poetry==$POETRY_VERSION

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-interaction --no-dev --no-ansi
```

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673221/warning-running-pip-as-the-root-user recommends with a user, is it not possible to simply supress the warning and continue using root ? pip version used is 21.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is discussed on the github, see the following links, I don't claim to be an expert on pip but this information was extremely helpful when I had something similar to this.

[See pfmoore's comment on May 28, 2021](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10028)

[See multiple comments below](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10556)

recommend looking at comments made by hholst80, pradyunsg, and potiuk on Oct 8, 2021

or as suggested by fnymnx:

[Check out this StackOverflow question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673221/warning-running-pip-as-the-root-user)