# Setting up Dockerfile to use non-root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip, dockerfile

I'm currently having an issue when I tried to run pip as a non-root user in my Dockerfile. When It starts to build the wheel it gives these warnings `WARNING: The script foo is installed in '/home/myuser/.local/bin' which is  not on PATH.` for pep8, sqlformat, isort, gunicorn, django-admin, epylint, pylint, pyreverse, and symilar.
In the current code I have, the build fails with the error `COPY failed: stat usr/src/app/wheels: file does not exist` when it tries to run `COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels` although it was failing earlier before I took out `--wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels` from line 35.

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.4-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8==3.9.2
COPY . .
RUN flake8 --ignore=E501,F401 .

# install dependencies
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
COPY --chown=myuser:myuser requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt
ENV PATH="/home/myuser/.local/bin:${PATH}"
COPY --chown=myuser:myuser . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.4-alpine

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint.prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g'  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh
RUN chmod +x  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# copy media files
COPY ./media/ $APP_HOME/mediafiles

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

I've tried tinkering with the WORKDIR, ENV PATH, and  RUN pip wheel.

Comment: In Docker you often don't want the `pip install --user` option; it's typical to install packages into the "system" Python and as root.  If you delete that `--user` option and all mentions of `myuser` (and ignore pip's warning about running as root) does it work better?

Comment: It was working better before I tried to not run pip as root, but isn't running pip as root bad practice?

Comment: Also see [WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673221/warning-running-pip-as-the-root-user), which discusses suppressing the warning and a virtual-environment-based alternative path.