# Kaggle pip installation warning

Tags: python, pip, kaggle

When I install a python package on kaggle, the package is successfully installed, but I get the following warning. The notebook is pinned to its original environment. I am running my notebooks on kaggle and don't see a way to use a virtual environment. My questions:

1. Is this something to be concerned about?
2. Is there a solution to the warning?

Python version:

```
3.7.12
```

The pip version:

```
pip 22.1.2
```

The warning:

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv class="ansi-yellow-fg">
```

I did see this post [WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673221/warning-running-pip-as-the-root-user/72551258#72551258) but I'm not clear on any required action, if any.

I posted a similar question on kaggle but never received a response.

Comment: in your kaggle , better to create an virtual environment and install package there in the environment not in your default python environment. rest if you want to make this error go in existing way just install packages as `pip install --user <package name>`

Comment: You can safely ignore this warning